# VSCode running Python Azure Function locally fails with ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am running VSCode 1.40.0 upgraded very recently on macOS 10.14.6, with Python 3.6.5 in a venv.  Prior to the upgrade, my code was working (week before last, the last time I did some work on it). This workspace is a set of Azure Functions, with the following launch.json configuration for running it:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9091,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
      "logToFile": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

The directory structure is:

```
.
-- env (python env)
-- SharedCode
---- FunctionApp.py
-- TLoginEvents
---- tlogins.py
```

When I run the code in VSCode, I get the following ModuleNotFoundError:

```
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM] Executed 'Functions.TLoginEvents' (Failed, Id=c6e6b342-4250-4041-8d19-8ce4ae8bb736)
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TLoginEvents. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM] Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SharedCode'
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM] Stack:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools/2.7.1846/workers/python/3.6/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 242, in _handle__function_load_request
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]     func_request.metadata.entry_point)
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools/2.7.1846/workers/python/3.6/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]     mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]   File "/Users/dylankaufman/Documents/Projects/SH/Data Pipeline/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]   File "/Users/dylankaufman/Documents/Projects/SH/Azure Functions/TLoginEvents/tlogins.py", line 1, in <module>
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM]     from SharedCode import FunctionApp
[11/13/19 5:17:08 PM] .
```

Though I never noticed it before, I do find it quite curious that the stack trace seems to be looking into the env for a different project (Data Pipeline) than the one I'm actually running.  The current project (Azure Functions) was created by copying the original directory wholesale, but I thought the whole point of the env was that it was local... (I'm still relatively new to Python & VSCode, so if anyone can explain that one, or point me at something that does, I'd appreciate it).

That said, I don't think that's really the issue.  If I run python3 in the same env in the Terminal window (even inside VSCode), I can run the import just fine, like so (this is in a stand-alone terminal window):

```
Dylans-iMac:Azure Functions dylankaufman$ source ./env/bin/activate
(env) Dylans-iMac:Azure Functions dylankaufman$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from SharedCode import FunctionApp
>>> import datetime
>>> app = FunctionApp.FunctionApp('test', datetime.datetime.utcnow())
>>> app.functionName
'test'
>>>
```

In case it is useful, here is the vscode settings.json:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "${workspacefolder}/env/bin/python",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
  "azureFunctions.templateFilter": "Verified",
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "Azure Functions.zip",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "func: pack --build-native-deps",
  "files.exclude": {
    "obj": true,
    "bin": true
  },
  "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "env",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

(note that I added ${workspacefolder} today as part of troubleshooting this, to no avail)

Thank you for any help/insight you can provide!

Dylan

Comment: I've read a whole bunch of articles about this issue.  I tried adding a parent directory ```__app__``` based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure, but now I just get a different error: ```No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,
issue is azure-function-core is trying to get any path from sys.path which match to same python version and checking for packages installed , it should find package from .venv site packages.
to resolve it I had removed all python path from  system environment variables , closed vscode and ran function again locally resolved issue for me.